# Chart.js doughnut-like radar chart (no anglelines in the center/empty center)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm looking to make a radarchart in chart.js with an empty center like this: [image: this]

Thus, I'm looking to make the angle line (the line going from the center) to start at 2 and the center to be a white pentagon in the following working example:

```js
radarChart = new Chart('radarCanvas',{
    "type": "radar",
    "data": {
        "labels": [
            "Management & Leadership",
            "Education & Teaching",
            "Research",
            "Impact",
            "Team"
        ],
        "datasets": [
            {
                "label": "4-3-21",
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(231,74,59,0.5)",
                "hoverBackgroundColor": "rgb(231,74,59,0.8)",
                "borderColor": "rgb(231,74,59)",
                "data": [
                    2.7,
                    3.8,
                    4.6,
                    2.2,
                    3.2
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "options": {
        "responsive": true,
        "maintainAspectRatio": false,
        "scale": {
            "angleLines": {
                "color": "rgb(90,92,105)"
            },
            "gridLines": {
                "color": "rgb(90,92,105)"
            },
            "ticks": {
                 max: 10,
                 min: 0,
                 stepSize: 2,
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="radarCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Solution I've tried sofar and their shortcomings:

**Change angleline options:** there exists no property that allows this in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#angle-line-options)

**Draw a dataset with a white backgroundcolor:**  dataset [2,2,2,2,2] for the above graph should perfectly cover the anglelines, but chart.js mixes the background color with overlaying datasets resulting in non-white overlay, also I have found no way of turning of labels for this dataset in the legenda resulting in a empty label next to the labels for the different datasets

**The internet**: I've found one [mention](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6234) of this being possible by the developers but have not been able to find the solution..

Answer (score 0):

You could try to achieve something like this by making the ticks scale negative (`min: -2`) and then using the `borderDash` configuration for `angleLines`. However, if the size of your chart changes, you will also need to adjust the 4th array number in `borderDash` accordingly.

The below code should render something like this for my screen size:

[image]

```js
radarChart = new Chart('radarCanvas', {
    "type": "radar",
    "data": {
        "labels": [
            "Management & Leadership",
            "Education & Teaching",
            "Research",
            "Impact",
            "Team"
        ],
        "datasets": [{
            "label": "4-3-21",
            "backgroundColor": "rgb(231,74,59,0.5)",
            "hoverBackgroundColor": "rgb(231,74,59,0.8)",
            "borderColor": "rgb(231,74,59)",
            "data": [
                2.7,
                3.8,
                4.6,
                2.2,
                3.2
            ]
        }]
    },
    "options": {
        "responsive": true,
        "maintainAspectRatio": false,
        "scale": {
            "angleLines": {
                "color": "rgb(90,92,105)",
                "lineWidth": 1,
                "borderDash": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    28,
                    150,
                    250
                ]
            },
            "gridLines": {
                "color": "rgb(90,92,105)"
            },
            "ticks": {
                "max": 10,
                "min": -2,
                "stepSize": 2,
                "callback": function(tickValue, index, ticks) {
                    if (tickValue >= -0) {
                        return tickValue
                    }
                    return null
                },
            },
            "max": 10,
            "min": -4,
            "beginAtZero": false
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="radarCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this effect by adding a dummy dataset with a white background and no borders or points.

This only works if you also don't need to display ticks (my case), otherwise the white polygon will overlap with them.

(Code taken from @Nicodemuz 's answer but updated for Chart.js v4.4.1)

```js
radarChart = new Chart('radarCanvas', {
    "type": "radar",
    "data": {
        "labels": [
            "Management & Leadership",
            "Education & Teaching",
            "Research",
            "Impact",
            "Team"
        ],
        "datasets": [
            {
                "label": "4-3-21",
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(231,74,59,0.3)",
                "hoverBackgroundColor": "rgb(231,74,59,0.6)",
                "borderColor": "rgb(231,74,59)",
                "data": [
                    2.7,
                    3.8,
                    4.6,
                    2.2,
                    3.2
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "",
                "backgroundColor": "white",
                "borderWidth": 0,
                "pointRadius": 0,
                "hoverBorderWidth": 0,
                "hoverPointRadius": 0,
                "data": [
                    0,0,0,0,0
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    "options": {
        "scales": {
            "r": {
                "max": 10,
                "min": -4,
                "beginAtZero": false,
                "ticks": {
                    "display": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.1"></script>
<canvas id="radarCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```